# For loop checking for cell without empty value and appending

Tags: python, excel, csv

New python coder here.

I want to get rid of rows of data and create a new data list where there ANY cell that is empty (or null) will not be appended into the new list.

Here is my code:

```
chippedlist=[]
for line in stringlist:         #for each row of data in datafile
    chippedline=[]
    inc=0
    for cell in line:               #for each cell in one row of data      
        inc+=1
    if inc == 13 and len(cell)== 0:
        chippedline=[]
        break
    else:
        if cell == cell[0]:
            firstcell=cell[1:]
            chippedline.append(firstcell)
        if cell != cell[0] and cell != cell[-1]:
            chippedcell=cell[2:-1]
            chippedline.append(chippedcell)
        if cell == cell[-1]:
            lastcell=cell[:0]
            chippedline.append(lastcell)
if len(chippedline) > 0:
    chippedlist.append(chippedline)
```

I have attached a sample of my data on this post.

As you can see, from the first row there is an empty cell at column 'N' (in the excel file), which is equivalent to the increment in which I have created 'inc == 13' (as index starts from 0 in python) I have created an increment for.

So if ANY cell in ANY row is empty (for example rows 15 & 18, Column Z and Column AA), I do not want to include that row into my new data set. However, somehow my first if statement in my for loop does not work.

However, it still appends the row with empty cells present into the new data set as shown in the Output below:

```
['17040200555', 'A', 'A60', 'LATEMADA60', 'EMAD ', 'LAT', 'KL', 'KL/E', 'SAI', 'HK', 'HK/E', 'E', 'EMA', '', 'SWH1', 'BHL0', '580', 'PYNEH', '2017-04-02 08:29:10', '2017-04-02 08:29:10', '2017-04-02 08:29:16', '2017-04-02 08:29:16', '2017-04-02 08:29:39', '2017-04-02 08:29:40', '2017-04-02 08:40:53', '2017-04-02 08:57:38', '2017-04-02 09:10:19', '2017-04-02 09:24:33', '1', '703', '3293', '1005', '0', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '', '', '0', '600', '2017-04-01 00:00:00', 'LAT', 'N-OTHERS', 'X600-ROSTER not foun', 'ssign to default 083', '030', '201704', '0800-0829', 'JC20170410P1.5.0', "2017-04-27 16:09:53'"]

['17040200554', 'A', 'A195', 'WONEMADA195', 'EMAD ', 'WON', 'KL', 'KL/E', 'LAI', 'KL', 'KL/W', 'E', 'EMA', '¥þ¨\\xad¥X¯l', 'LCK2', 'CHE0', '185', 'CMC', '2017-04-02 08:28:38', '2017-04-02 08:28:38', '2017-04-02 08:28:48', '2017-04-02 08:28:48', '2017-04-02 08:29:04', '2017-04-02 08:29:05', '2017-04-02 08:31:35', '2017-04-02 08:39:00', '2017-04-02 08:43:17', '2017-04-02 08:57:36', '1', '177', '1711', '445', '0', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '', '', '0', '1135715', '2017-04-01 00:00:00', 'WON', 'D-0730', 'B3-No Roster foun', 'leet group to same depot/OIC:WON TAM TSZ YEUNG X600', '201704', '0800-0829', 'JC20170410P1.5.0', "2017-04-27 16:09:53'"]

['17040200553', 'A', 'A63', 'CASEMASA63', 'EMAS ', 'CAS', 'NT', 'NT/NW', 'CAS', 'NT', 'NT/NW', 'E', 'EMA', 'SLIP', 'CPB2', 'CAS0', '148', 'TMH', '2017-04-02 08:27:56', '2017-04-02 08:27:56', '2017-04-02 08:28:02', '2017-04-02 08:28:02', '2017-04-02 08:28:19', '2017-04-02 08:28:52', '2017-04-02 08:34:58', '2017-04-02 08:58:52', '2017-04-02 09:11:57', '2017-04-02 09:24:59', '1', '422', '3367', '1434', '0', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '', '', '0', '600', '2017-04-01 00:00:00', 'CAS', 'N-OTHERS', 'X600-ROSTER not foun', 'ssign to default 083', '030', '201704', '0800-0829', 'JC20170410P1.5.0', "2017-04-27 16:09:53'"]

['17040200552', 'A', 'A125', 'ALCEMADA125', 'EMAD ', 'ALC', 'HK', 'HK/W', 'ABD', 'HK', 'HK/W', 'E', 'EMA', 'FEVER', 'ALC1', 'ABD0', '495', 'QMH', '2017-04-02 08:27:38', '2017-04-02 08:27:38', '2017-04-02 08:27:47', '2017-04-02 08:27:47', '2017-04-02 08:27:53', '2017-04-02 08:27:54', '2017-04-02 08:36:09', '2017-04-02 08:51:29', '2017-04-02 09:08:26', '2017-04-02 09:22:05', '1', '511', '3251', '920', '0', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '', '', '0', '600', '2017-04-01 00:00:00', 'ALC', 'N-OTHERS', 'X600-ROSTER not foun', 'ssign to default 083', '030', '201704', '0800-0829', 'JC20170410P1.5.0', "2017-04-27 16:09:53'"]

['17040200551', 'A', 'A192', 'POLEMADA192', 'EMAD ', 'POL', 'KL', 'KL/E', 'POL', 'KL', 'KL/E', 'E', 'EMA1', '', 'PLM9', 'POL0', '339', 'UCH', '2017-04-02 08:27:47', '2017-04-02 08:27:47', '2017-04-02 08:27:52', '2017-04-02 08:27:52', '2017-04-02 08:28:35', '2017-04-02 08:28:36', '2017-04-02 08:34:57', '2017-04-02 08:45:18', '2017-04-02 09:05:48', '2017-04-02 09:19:52', '1', '430', '3076', '621', '0', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', '', '', '1136057', '1136057', '2017-04-01 00:00:00', 'POL', 'N-2030', 'A1-Roster found', '201704', '0800-0829', 'JC20170410P1.5.0', "2017-04-27 16:09:53'"]
```

Additional Info:

I used csv.reader to read my original file into python.

1. Original file is a .csv file
2. I used newline= '', delimited = ',',
   quotechar = '"'
3. I then converted the .csv file into a list of
   strings using .split()

Can anyone help please :)

Thanks in advance!

[Data Sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b1q75u3z6cx3jsj/sample.csv?dl=0)

Comment: Just edited my post, sorry my very first post, didn't know how to make the block of code's format appear properly. Should be fine now

Comment: In your sample, `AN` and `AO` columns are always empty. What do you want to do in that case? So wouldn't the resulting output be empty?

Comment: @Jay Yes, I would want to get rid of those 2 columns in my final dataset (not include them in my final dataset).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comments, you also want to skip the `AN` and `AO` columns, which are all zero in your case. This small snippet should work for you -

```
f = open('sample.csv', 'r')
raw_data = f.readlines()
stringlist = [line.strip().split(',') for line in raw_data]

chippedlist = []
for line in stringlist:  # for each row of data in datafile
    if '' in line[:39] or '' in line[42:]:  # column AN=40, check whether '' is in the list
        continue
    else:
        chippedlist.append(line[:39] + line[42:])
```

You can extend it further as per your requirement.
Here is the resulting chippedlist from your input file -

```
['17040200554', 'A', 'A195', 'WONEMADA195', 'EMAD ', 'WON', 'KL', 'KL/E', 'LAI', 'KL', 'KL/W', 'E', 'EMA', '\xa5\xfe\xa8\xad\xa5X\xafl', 'LCK2', 'CHE0', '185', 'CMC', '2017-04-02 08:28:38', '2017-04-02 08:28:38', '2017-04-02 08:28:48', '2017-04-02 08:28:48', '2017-04-02 08:29:04', '2017-04-02 08:29:05', '2017-04-02 08:31:35', '2017-04-02 08:39:00', '2017-04-02 08:43:17', '2017-04-02 08:57:36', '1', '177', '1711', '445', '0', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '1135715', '2017-04-01 00:00:00', 'WON', 'D-0730', '"B3-No Roster found', ' Fleet group to same depot/OIC:WON TAM TSZ YEUNG X600"', '201704', '0800-0829', 'JC20170410P1.5.0', '2017-04-27 16:09:53']
['17040200553', 'A', 'A63', 'CASEMASA63', 'EMAS ', 'CAS', 'NT', 'NT/NW', 'CAS', 'NT', 'NT/NW', 'E', 'EMA', 'SLIP', 'CPB2', 'CAS0', '148', 'TMH', '2017-04-02 08:27:56', '2017-04-02 08:27:56', '2017-04-02 08:28:02', '2017-04-02 08:28:02', '2017-04-02 08:28:19', '2017-04-02 08:28:52', '2017-04-02 08:34:58', '2017-04-02 08:58:52', '2017-04-02 09:11:57', '2017-04-02 09:24:59', '1', '422', '3367', '1434', '0', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '600', '2017-04-01 00:00:00', 'CAS', 'N-OTHERS', '"X600-ROSTER not found', ' assign to default 0830', ' 2030"', '201704', '0800-0829', 'JC20170410P1.5.0', '2017-04-27 16:09:53']
['17040200552', 'A', 'A125', 'ALCEMADA125', 'EMAD ', 'ALC', 'HK', 'HK/W', 'ABD', 'HK', 'HK/W', 'E', 'EMA', 'FEVER', 'ALC1', 'ABD0', '495', 'QMH', '2017-04-02 08:27:38', '2017-04-02 08:27:38', '2017-04-02 08:27:47', '2017-04-02 08:27:47', '2017-04-02 08:27:53', '2017-04-02 08:27:54', '2017-04-02 08:36:09', '2017-04-02 08:51:29', '2017-04-02 09:08:26', '2017-04-02 09:22:05', '1', '511', '3251', '920', '0', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '600', '2017-04-01 00:00:00', 'ALC', 'N-OTHERS', '"X600-ROSTER not found', ' assign to default 0830', ' 2030"', '201704', '0800-0829', 'JC20170410P1.5.0', '2017-04-27 16:09:53']
['17040200550', 'A', 'A266', 'LATEMADA266', 'EMAD ', 'LAT', 'KL', 'KL/E', 'LAT', 'KL', 'KL/E', 'E', 'EMA', 'FOOT PAIN X MOVE', 'KTG2', 'KTG2', '89', 'UCH', '2017-04-02 08:27:24', '2017-04-02 08:27:24', '2017-04-02 08:27:33', '2017-04-02 08:27:33', '2017-04-02 08:27:57', '2017-04-02 08:27:58', '2017-04-02 08:34:30', '2017-04-02 09:27:41', '2017-04-02 09:37:56', '2017-04-02 09:51:05', '1', '426', '4987', '3191', '0', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '600', '2017-04-01 00:00:00', 'LAT', 'N-OTHERS', '"X600-ROSTER not found', ' assign to default 0830', ' 2030"', '201704', '0800-0829', 'JC20170410P1.5.0', '2017-04-27 16:09:53']
['17040200548', 'A', 'A252', 'WONEMADA252', 'EMAD ', 'WON', 'KL', 'KL/E', 'WON', 'KL', 'KL/E', 'E', 'EMAFR', 'FR(SOB)', 'WTS2', 'WON0', '247', 'QEH', '2017-04-02 08:26:24', '2017-04-02 08:26:24', '2017-04-02 08:26:35', '2017-04-02 08:26:35', '2017-04-02 08:27:09', '2017-04-02 08:28:04', '2017-04-02 08:32:52', '2017-04-02 08:50:05', '2017-04-02 09:19:08', '2017-04-02 09:33:12', '1', '388', '3908', '1033', '0', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '600', '2017-04-01 00:00:00', 'WON', 'N-OTHERS', '"X600-ROSTER not found', ' assign to default 0830', ' 2030"', '201704', '0800-0829', 'JC20170410P1.5.0', '2017-04-27 16:09:53']
['17040200545', 'A', 'A93', 'FANEMADA93', 'EMAD ', 'FAN', 'NT', 'NT/NE', 'SHE', 'NT', 'NT/NE', 'E', 'EMAFR', 'FR(COLL)', 'SSI1', 'FAN0', '223', 'NDH', '2017-04-02 08:22:45', '2017-04-02 08:22:45', '2017-04-02 08:22:54', '2017-04-02 08:22:54', '2017-04-02 08:24:04', '2017-04-02 08:24:05', '2017-04-02 08:26:49', '2017-04-02 08:32:37', '2017-04-02 08:46:49', '2017-04-02 09:12:03', '1', '244', '2878', '348', '0', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '1140591', '2017-04-01 00:00:00', 'FAN', 'N-2030', 'A1-Roster found', '201704', '0800-0829', 'JC20170410P1.5.0', '2017-04-27 16:09:53']
['17040200543', 'A', 'A171', 'SAIEMADA171', 'EMAD ', 'SAI', 'HK', 'HK/E', 'SAI', 'HK', 'HK/E', 'E', 'EMAFR', 'FR(SOB)', 'CWN2', 'SKW2', '143', 'PYNEH', '2017-04-02 08:22:18', '2017-04-02 08:22:18', '2017-04-02 08:22:46', '2017-04-02 08:22:47', '2017-04-02 08:22:59', '2017-04-02 08:23:00', '2017-04-02 08:25:56', '2017-04-02 08:41:06', '2017-04-02 08:48:28', '2017-04-02 09:02:49', '1', '218', '2389', '910', '0', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '1137452', '2017-04-01 00:00:00', 'SAI', 'D-0730', '"B3-No Roster found', ' Fleet group to same depot/OIC:SAI KONG KING TONG X600"', '201704', '0800-0829', 'JC20170410P1.5.0', '2017-04-27 16:09:53']
['17040200541', 'A', 'A217', 'KTKEMADA217', 'EMAD ', 'KTK', 'KL', 'KL/E', 'NGA', 'KL', 'KL/E', 'E', 'EMA', '\xa5\xfe\xa8\xad\xb5L\xa4O', 'KBY3', 'KTK0', '233', 'UCH', '2017-04-02 08:19:23', '2017-04-02 08:19:23', '2017-04-02 08:19:29', '2017-04-02 08:19:29', '2017-04-02 08:20:16', '2017-04-02 08:20:17', '2017-04-02 08:24:18', '2017-04-02 08:33:57', '2017-04-02 08:44:47', '2017-04-02 08:59:48', '1', '295', '2371', '579', '0', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '1140660', '2017-04-01 00:00:00', 'KTK', 'N-2030', 'A1-Roster found', '201704', '0800-0829', 'JC20170410P1.5.0', '2017-04-27 16:09:53']
['17040200540', 'A', 'A260', 'TAIEMADA260', 'EMAD ', 'TAI', 'NT', 'NT/NE', 'TAI', 'NT', 'NT/NE', 'E', 'EMA', 'DIZZ', 'TPO1', 'TAI0', '188', 'AHNH', '2017-04-02 08:18:53', '2017-04-02 08:18:53', '2017-04-02 08:18:58', '2017-04-02 08:18:58', '2017-04-02 08:19:12', '2017-04-02 08:19:13', '2017-04-02 08:25:27', '2017-04-02 08:43:38', '2017-04-02 08:48:37', '2017-04-02 09:02:01', '1', '394', '2568', '1091', '0', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '1135828', '2017-04-01 00:00:00', 'TAI', 'D-0730', '"B3-No Roster found', ' Fleet group to same depot/OIC:TAI CHAN CHUNG FU X600"', '201704', '0800-0829', 'JC20170410P1.5.0', '2017-04-27 16:09:53']
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much @Jay! You've made my code so much simpler, I knew I was overthinking on some bits of the code! :)